# How to sketch a curve given its intrinsic equation

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

I'm wondering what the best method of sketching a curve is, if you know the coordinates of a point on the line and  its intrinsic equation in the form:
$$
s=f(\psi)
$$
where s is arc length from the origin to a point on the curve and where $$tan(\psi )=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

When attempting a problem I tried to convert the equation to cartesian following a method online but I ended up getting an integral which is unsolvable with my level of maths

I'm wondering if there is another method of sketching this curve.

Thank you for any replies

Comment: *"I ended up getting an integral which is unsolvable with my level of maths"* ... If it makes you feel any better, *most* integrals are "unsolvable" with *any* level of maths ...  in the sense that they don't admit closed-form formulas using elementary functions. Such integrals are simply evaluated with numerical methods, which computers can crunch through to whatever level of precision is desired. ... To add context to your question, you should include the particular problem you were facing, so that answerers don't have to talk in vague general terms.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for your comment, I would have included the particular problem and will going forwards but here it was part of a homework assignment that I haven't submitted yet and I didn't want to cheat on it.

Comment: Do you mean you're given a point of the curve, or you know the coordinates of any point of the curve? If the latter is meant, what are these coordinates functions of?

Comment: @Allawonder a point of the curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can invert the given equation $s=f(\psi)$ to an explicit equation of the form
$$\psi=\psi(s)\ .$$
The curve has an arc length parametrization of the form
$$s\mapsto\bigl(x(s),y(s)\bigr)\ ,$$
and one has $$\dot x(s)=\cos\psi(s),\qquad\dot y(s)=\sin\psi(s)\ .$$
This allows to find $s\mapsto\bigl(x(s),y(s)\bigr)$ explicitly or numerically.

Answer (score 1):

Graphically, you can start from the solution of $f(\psi)=0$ and draw a line segment in the direction of $\psi$. Then take a small increment, compute $s'=f(\psi+\delta)$ and mark the point at distance $s'$ on the line segment. Draw the line segment in the direction of $\phi+\delta$, compute $s''=f(\phi+2\delta)$ and mark the point at distance $s''-s'$...

Iterate at will. This is in fact a graphical resolution of the differential equation.

If you find that too tedious ($\delta$ should be tiny), use a numerical solver such as RK4.

---

Improved graphical method:

Rather than working with line segments, you can use circular arcs. When you give $\phi$ an increment, the corresponding increment of $s$ allows you to compute the radius of the arc, $$r=\dfrac{\Delta s}{\Delta\psi}.$$

Answer (score 1):

From the differential equation given, we can tell that the curve (provided we assume it is continuous) has a slope that varies from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ as $x$ increases. Thus it is something $\cup$-shaped, like, at least at the endpoints, that is for $\psi=\pmπ/2.$

If you gave the exact form of $f,$ perhaps we might be able to say more. But from the differential equation alone, assuming $y$ is a single-valued function of $x,$ then the above is the picture that appears.